# Custom layout for Orchard CMS head section. Reordering of style, script, meta

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, orchardcms

Is there a way to customize the layout of `@Display(Model.Head)`?

Orchard currently places meta tags below scripts and fav-ico below that.
I'd like to reorder these.

Comment: Why do you care about the order?

Comment: There is no functional reason to keep them grouped together or ordered. I prefer that have them in a certain way and am just curious.

Comment: The code that does that is in CoreShapes, but so much would have to be overridden, for a completely inconsequential result, that it really doesn't seem worth the trouble.

Comment: Was hoping for an easy, inconsequential result. :)